# Video playback with QtQuick

Tags: qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I wanted to render a video from a webcam in the background of a qt quick application.
I used this code from 5.1.1 documentation to render a test video:

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtMultimedia 5.0

    Item {
        MediaPlayer {
            id: mediaplayer
            source: "groovy_video.mp4"
        }

        VideoOutput {
            anchors: parent.fill
            source: mediaplayer
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: playArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
        }
    }
```

I have no QtQuick experience and it is double frustrating if not even the example (unmodified) is working:

```
Invalid property assignment: "anchors" is a read-only property 
anchors: parent.fill
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It's error with documentation, correct syntax are not "anchors: parent.fill", but "anchors.fill: parent" (like in MouseArea). Which page of documentation? For fix it

Comment: @Guillaume Belz here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

This might fix it:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Item {
    height: video.implicitHeight // or video.height
    width: video.implicitWidth // or video.width
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "groovy_video.mp4"
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: video
        source: mediaplayer
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
    }
}
```